# Desigining ui for 44 inch android device

Tags: android, user-interface

Now am designing pixel c for ui development and testing in micromax 40 inch tv . if i run the same application in 44 inch android device am getting lots of ui issues , how can i design ui for 44 inch device?

Comment: did you tried `AndroidTVActivity` ?

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://developer.android.com/design/tv/index.html

Comment: No am designing for an iot device with resolution 1980*1080 . am using 40 inch for output purpose.

Comment: @VivekMishra there is no such thing like `AndroidTVActivity` in the SDK

Comment: @pskink when creating new activity by right clicking on java pavkage it shows option for `AndroidTVActivity` in the dropdown. Though it requires minimum sdk to be 21

Comment: @VivekMishra still it has little to do with OP question